# Why am I getting an error with this trigger's FOR loops?

Tags: sql, triggers, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to create a trigger in a SQL interpreter, and I'm having some head-scratching problems with it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_permission_role_rel_update AFTER UPDATE ON permission_role_rel
REFERENCING NEW ROW as newrow OLD ROW as oldrow 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC

    /* delete old row */
    FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(MYSCHEMA.simulate_by_permission_role_rel(oldrow.id_role, oldrow.id_permission)) simulationA
    DO
    CALL MYSCHEMA.log_proc('DELETE', 'SECVAL', 'test', '{}');
    END FOR;

    /* insert new row */
    FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(MYSCHEMA.simulate_by_permission_role_rel(newrow.id_role, newrow.id_permission)) simulationB
    DO
    CALL MYSCHEMA.log_proc('INSERT', 'SECVAL', '{}', 'test');
    END FOR;
END;
```

The statement above results in an error claiming the end-of-instruction isn't valid, and highlighting the end of the second CALL as the culprit.

```
SQL State: 42601
Vendor Code: -104
Message: [SQL0104] Token <END-OF-INSTRUCTION> was not valid. Valid tokens: ;.
```

Both FOR loops work independently, just not when they are both together under the same trigger. I don't really know what more to try. What am I doing wrong here? And why would a single FOR loop work, but not two?

Thank you.

**EDIT**
(edited for more info)

I'm running under DB2 on iSeries, i5/OS 7.1. I'm also running all SQL statements through iNavigator.

**EDIT #2**

All the triggers seem to be created with these properties:

```
...
FOR EACH ROW 
MODE DB2SQL 

SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
COMMIT = *NONE , 
DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
DFTRDBCOL = MYSCHEMA, 
DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
SRTSEQ = *HEX   
BEGIN
...
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.LOG_PROC ( 
    IN OP VARCHAR(6) , 
    IN TABLENAME VARCHAR(128) , 
    IN OLDVAL VARCHAR(255) , 
    IN NEWVAL VARCHAR(255) ) 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC MYSCHEMA.LOG_PROC 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = MYSCHEMA , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO AA_LEGACYLOG ( OPERATION , TABLENAME , OLDVALUE , NEWVALUE ) VALUES ( OP , TABLENAME , OLDVAL , NEWVAL ) ; 
END  ;
```

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.SIMULATE_BY_PERMISSION_ROLE_REL ( 
    ARG_ID_ROLE INTEGER , 
    ARG_ID_PERMISSION INTEGER ) 
    RETURNS TABLE ( 
    USRCODE VARCHAR(10) , 
    SECURABLE VARCHAR(12) , 
    LG_INDX VARCHAR(1) , 
    LG_VALO VARCHAR(10) , 
    LG_ATRB VARCHAR(6) )   
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC MYSCHEMA.SIMULATE_BY_PERMISSION_ROLE_REL 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    READS SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = MYSCHEMA , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    RETURN ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT A . USER_REF , P . SECURABLE , P . LG_INDX , P . LG_VALO , P . LG_ATRB 
        FROM ROLE R , PERMISSION P , ACTOR A , ACTOR_ROLE_REL 

        WHERE R . ID = ARG_ID_ROLE 
        AND P . ID = ARG_ID_PERMISSION   

        AND ACTOR_ROLE_REL . ID_ACTOR = ACTOR . ID 
        AND ACTOR_ROLE_REL . ID_ROLE = R . ID 

        GROUP BY A . USER_REF , P . SECURABLE , P . LG_INDX , P . LG_VALO , P . LG_ATRB  
    )  ;
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger/13271559#13271559

Comment: I can't seem to change the terminator character at all. I've also tried --#SET TERMINATOR %, but also does not work. It doesn't seem to be supported by db2 for iseries, though I'm having no luck in finding a working alternative so far (I'm using ibm's i navigator). Any ideas?

Comment: What OS version is DB2 on? (Also possibly what is the DB2 group PTF level?) What does `create a trigger in a SQL interpreter` mean? Is it all via iNav (which merely sends statements to the server)? The statement terminator is not a problem here.

Comment: BTW, the trigger creation properties should be edited into the question.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is all through iNav. I don't have access to the system right now, but I'll edit the question in the morning. What do you mean by trigger creation properties though?

Comment: Drill down in iNav to the schema. Click 'Triggers' and generate the SQL for that trigger. The full _creation properties_ are then available to copy. You have your CREATE TABLE statement originally in the question, but a lot of defaults get applied. Post the full set, and we can compare against other systems.

Comment: Also, your trigger references a TABLE() function and a stored proc. We should probably see the creation properties for those so that we understand how the trigger, function and proc fit together. I'd like to compile three similar objects and see what happens here.

Comment: I had no idea properties were added automatically... I've added the details to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

This is presumably a duplicate of [Error SQL0104 when creating a function in System i V7R1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916796/4801598); the link I gave is to a specific answer in that discussion, but probably best to read the entire discussion. That discussion makes a similar conclusion I make below, that the issue is per lack of PTFs\maintenance applied to the IBM i 7.1 system used by the OP, for an issue\defect with parsing a *FOR statement* [IBM i 7.10->Database->Reference->SQL reference->SQL control statements->FOR statement](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzforstmt.htm) when not including the optional `cursor-name CURSOR FOR`clause; i.e. the *optional* clause is actually *mandatory* **until** the fix has been applied.

The following script, which should be sufficiently *like* what the OP gave [omits the DFTRDBCOL in each SET OPTION and hard-coded return on the UDTF], runs fine to create the trigger, *without any terminating errors*, on IBM i 7.1 with cumulative maintenance from 2015/317, using both the RUNSQLSTM server-side tooling\SQL-script-processor and the iACS Run SQL [I do not have a Win OS on which to load and try iNav] client tooling\SQL-script-processor.  Note: the last DROP at the end of the script is just an extra statement that will fail, placed there to emphasize that the superfluous semicolon after the END for the BEGIN in the trigger causes no difficulties and I even added yet another semicolon as a statement-separator, and that also causes no difficulties.  I suppose either a defect was corrected\removed since the OP's issue, or

```
drop   table qtemp.AA_LEGACYLOG
;
create table qtemp.AA_LEGACYLOG
  ( OPERATION         VARCHAR(  6)
  , TABLENAME         VARCHAR(128)
  , OLDVALUE          VARCHAR(255)
  , NEWVALUE          VARCHAR(255)
  )
;
drop   PROCEDURE  LOG_PROC
;
CREATE PROCEDURE  LOG_PROC
 (  IN OP VARCHAR(6)
 ,  IN TABLENAME VARCHAR(128)
 ,  IN OLDVAL VARCHAR(255)
 ,  IN NEWVAL VARCHAR(255)
 )  LANGUAGE SQL
    SPECIFIC  LOG_PROC
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD
             ,  ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE
             ,  COMMIT = *NONE
             ,  DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00)
             ,  DYNDFTCOL = *NO
             ,  DYNUSRPRF = *USER
             ,  SRTSEQ = *HEX
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO QTEMP.AA_LEGACYLOG
      ( OPERATION , TABLENAME , OLDVALUE , NEWVALUE )  VALUES
      (        OP , TABLENAME , OLDVAL   , NEWVAL   )
    ;
END
;
drop table    permission_role_rel
;
create table  permission_role_rel
( ID_ROLE       INTEGER
, ID_PERMISSION INTEGER
)
;
drop   FUNCTION  SIMULATE_BY_PERMISSION_ROLE_REL
;
CREATE FUNCTION  SIMULATE_BY_PERMISSION_ROLE_REL
  ( ARG_ID_ROLE INTEGER
  , ARG_ID_PERMISSION INTEGER
  ) RETURNS TABLE
  ( USRCODE VARCHAR(10)
  , SECURABLE VARCHAR(12)
  , LG_INDX VARCHAR(1)
  , LG_VALO VARCHAR(10)
  , LG_ATRB VARCHAR(6)
  ) LANGUAGE SQL
    SPECIFIC  SIMULATE_BY_PERMISSION_ROLE_REL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD
  , ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE
  , COMMIT = *NONE
  , DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00)
  , DYNDFTCOL = *NO
  , DYNUSRPRF = *USER
  , SRTSEQ = *HEX
RETURN
 ( select 'code', 'capable', 'I', 'VALO', 'ATTR'
   from qsys2.qsqptabl
 )
;
CREATE TRIGGER log_permission_role_rel_update
       AFTER UPDATE ON permission_role_rel
REFERENCING NEW ROW as newrow
            OLD ROW as oldrow
FOR EACH ROW
MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC

    /* delete old row */
    FOR SELECT *
        FROM TABLE
          ( simulate_by_permission_role_rel(oldrow.id_role, oldrow.id_permission)
          ) simulationA
    DO
      CALL log_proc('DELETE', 'SECVAL', 'test', '{}') ;
    END FOR;

   /* insert new row */
    FOR SELECT *
        FROM TABLE
          ( simulate_by_permission_role_rel(newrow.id_role, newrow.id_permission)
          ) simulationB
    DO
      CALL log_proc('INSERT', 'SECVAL', '{}', 'test');
    END FOR;
END;
;
drop table qtemp.permission_test
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have semicolons ending lines within your function, as well as a semicolon ending your function declaration.  End your function declaration with an @ sign like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.SIMULATE_BY_PERMISSION_ROLE_REL ( 
    ARG_ID_ROLE INTEGER , 
    ARG_ID_PERMISSION INTEGER ) 
    RETURNS TABLE ( 
    USRCODE VARCHAR(10) , 
    SECURABLE VARCHAR(12) , 
    LG_INDX VARCHAR(1) , 
    LG_VALO VARCHAR(10) , 
    LG_ATRB VARCHAR(6) )   
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC MYSCHEMA.SIMULATE_BY_PERMISSION_ROLE_REL 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    READS SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = MYSCHEMA , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    RETURN ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT A . USER_REF , P . SECURABLE , P . LG_INDX , P . LG_VALO , P . LG_ATRB 
        FROM ROLE R , PERMISSION P , ACTOR A , ACTOR_ROLE_REL 

        WHERE R . ID = ARG_ID_ROLE 
        AND P . ID = ARG_ID_PERMISSION   

        AND ACTOR_ROLE_REL . ID_ACTOR = ACTOR . ID 
        AND ACTOR_ROLE_REL . ID_ROLE = R . ID 

        GROUP BY A . USER_REF , P . SECURABLE , P . LG_INDX , P . LG_VALO , P . LG_ATRB  
    ) @
```

Then save that to a file c:\db\simulate_by_permission_role_rel.sql

Then execute that using the following:

```
db2 connect to mydb
db2 -td@ -f c:\db\simulate_by_permission_role_rel.sql
db2 connect reset
```

The -td@ tells the db2 command line interface to interpret the @ sign as the statement terminator.  The -f tells the db2 cli which file to execute.

Comment: Note that the OP was not using the "db2 command line interface". Instead, a client-based SQL [the iNav Run SQL] scripting environment was being utilized. In my experience, the DB2 for i SQL parser\syntax-checker has no difficulty to treat the trailing semicolon as a statement-separator [or statement-terminator]; i.e. no error other than possibly a low-severity\non-terminating "empty statement" would be issued per the inclusion of a superfluous trailing semicolon. The CREATE TRIGGER source of the OP compiles without error in the Run SQL Statement (RUNSQLSTM) interpreter of IBM DB2 for i 7.1